# Site doesn't stop loading on Firefox and $(window).load never gets called

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firefox, dom-events, loading

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now. This is a Wordpress multi-site where one of the sites never stops loading and there are two functions that I am calling on `$(window).load` event but they never get triggered (Those are the rendering of the images on the viewport and the same for the ads)... if I use `$(document).ready` it will work but I wouldn't be solving the real issue as the page still shows as loading all the time event thought the content seems to be completely loaded.

This happens only on Firefox and I have tried in several computers... other browsers work fine.

I have read that this may be a problem with Javascript but there are a lot of Javascript resources I don't know where to begin. I have been looking around on the js resources but haven't found anything that could be causing this issue.
Any suggestions on how to find the root cause of this?

Here is a link for one of the pages with the issue:

http://www.motortrend.com/cars/toyota/rav4/2017/

Comment: It should be `$(window).on("load", callback)`, not the deprecated `$(window).load`.

Comment: Sorry... you're right... but that doesn't work either... the root issue is that the page never stops loading so those events never get triggered

Comment: After observing that page with the Network tab of the developer tools open, it appears that this page continuously makes requests, which means that the load event will not fire.

Comment: I would suggest to comment out each part (loops!) of the site and check if the issue occurred.